# Why features extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

In pattern recognition why is it important feature extraction? Why we have to reduce the feature space? Is only a computational problem or this procedure improves the generalization ability of a classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature extraction is not just about computational complexity. For a fixed number of training samples, if the number of features becomes sufficiently large, performance of the classifier can decrease significantly. See [Curse of Dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

As a practical case, consider a classifier using multivariate normal statistics (mean and covariance). For `N` training samples and `k` features, the covariance matrix will become singular for `N < k`. Therefore, if the number of samples cannot be increased, it is necessary to reduce the number of features in order to use the classifier.

Comment: This is only true if you do not use regularization, which is used basically all the time.

Comment: @AndreasMueller It would be great if you could expand on that comment or perhaps provide some references. I've used feature extraction - and seen it used - in numerous contexts and regularization was definitely not "used basically all the time."

Comment: Regularization not for feature extraction but for the supervised task. For example in text classification, the number of features is the size of the dictionary (or even larger), so ``n_samples << n_features`` very regularly. That is not really a problem if you use regularization, though.

Comment: Except the question is specifically about feature extraction and why it is done. It may not be as relevant to text classification, where the desired features often *are* the counts/frequencies of the dictionary words but it is very relevant and frequently used for other classification problems. It should also be noted that regularization isn't "free" since it has the side-effect of introducing bias into the estimator/classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Both: a smaller feature space is (obviously?) more tractable, and eliminating unimportant details removes things that need to be generalized "around".